# Why is there an election now?

Tags: support, status-completed, election

A new election phase has been launched. I am suprised that there is only one candidate (thank you to him). I would like to know why two moderators are expected now. Are some of the 5 current moderators stopping ? Did the size of GIS SE increase so much that new moderators are needed ?

Maybe if we knew better why we need candidates, this could attract new candidates. The tasks seem to be very time consuming, so you need good reason to invest yourself.

Comment: One mod is stepping down, GIS traffic is up to 30k per (week)day http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/why-is-gis-stack-exchange-so-popular-of-late need to spread the load out.

Comment: GIS-SE average handling time 5 hours 28 minutes currently, this use to be below 2 hours (this does vary depending on if week or weekend)

Comment: @Mapperz, what is the "GIS-SE average handling time"? The average of time users spend on GIS SE?

Comment: @AndreSilva Handling time is the time it take from when community members flag a post for mods attention it is the window of turn-around time for it to be addressed.

Comment: I thought it may have been in part prompted by this Meta Q&A: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3670/election-schedule

Comment: I just noticed that GIS SE is currently ranked 12th amongst all Stack Exchange sites in terms of new questions per day: http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new Moderator election now because a) I am stepping down from the post, and b) GIS Stack Exchange is successful.

I'm stepping down because my work and home duties have changed such that now I only have time to visit GIS-se a few times a week, and occasionally not at all.

I remain as committed to the site as ever, I've been here since the earliest days in beta, but it has always been a "in my 'free' time" kind of affair. (And, in the course of time, much of "free" has been liberally stolen from other places... :-)

It's just not fair to my fellow moderators or the community to be in a drivers seat and yet twitching the reins lightly and rarely.

That said, even if my involvement had remained constant, we've still reached the point where another moderator or two is warranted -- GIS-se is working!!

As @Mapperz notes we're up to 30k visitors a day during the week, and the number of items in the moderating queue has risen proportionally.

Comment: +1 Thanks for weighing in.  We are fielding over 100 (highly diverse) questions daily--and this is one of the slack times of year.  In another month the activity will likely rise considerably.